# READELF - How to add "@GLIBX_XXX" after symbol name

Tags: c, linux, elf, readelf

I'm learning ELF, and was given a task to create a custom READELF program in C 32bit linux.

As part of my task, I created pointers to the '.symtab' and the '.strtab' tables, so I could print each symbol name. However, when comparing my output to the original READELF output, I noticed that I'm missing the "@..." part after some of the symbol names.

Where can I find this data?

Comment: Are you asking how to *generate* the symbol from a Linux ELF program written in C (because you have the [tag:c] and [tag:linux] tags), or about the ELF file format?  Using GNU C tools, you use the [symver](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) function attribute to specify the symbol version; with GNU assembler (as), you use the .symver directive.  As to the ELF file format, look at the .gnu.version section (of type SHT_GNU_versym); see [man 5 elf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

Comment: I think you are asking about how what symbol properties `readelf` is representing with the `@GLIB_XXX` appended to some of the symbol names.  That would be symbol *versions*.

Comment: @Glärbo - I set up a pointer to the versym table like so: Elf32_Half *versym_table = (Elf32_Half *)((int)header + shdr[versymTableIndex].sh_offset).

But given a symbol index, how can I extract its version from te versym table?

Comment: I haven't written my own ELF file parser, but I do believe the details you need are described in the Linux Standard Base version 1.2, Chapter 6. [Symbol Versioning](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.2.0/gLSB/symversion.html).

Comment: @Glärbo - I appreciate your help, but I'm still having trouble printing the version name. From the link you attached to your comment, I gathered that I need to access the string table associated with the .gnu.version_d table. However, I couldn't find the relevant offset in the .gnu.version_d table that points to the relevant entry in that string table.

Comment: @Johnny: the vd_aux field in the .gnu.version_d table entry gives the offset to the Elf32_Verdaux table for that particular entry (and it has vd_cnt entries, because a symbol *can* have multiple versions). In the Elf32_Verdaux table, the vda_name fields in each entry are the offset to the version or dependency name string in the section header, in bytes.  Have you considered making a simple single versioned dynamic symbol object file, and tracing it by hand first?